# Excel Export working in Firefox but not IE

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, firefox, internet-explorer-8, export-to-excel

I have Excel Export functionality in my MVC App. The way this works is, I use this line:

```
window.open((actionUrl + "?id=" + guid + "&viewName=" + viewUrl + "&fileName="  + fileName), null, null, null);
```

This enables me to pass all of my parameters to the MVC action through the URL. The action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(Guid? id, string viewName, string fileName)
        {
            IndicationBase indication = CachedTransactionManager<IndicationBase>.GetCachedTransactions(id.Value);
            return new ExcelResult<Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.ModelBase>
            (
                ControllerContext,
                viewName,
                fileName,
                indication.Model
            );
        }
```

It then calls the Excel Result which looks like this:

```
public class ExcelResult<Model> : ActionResult
    {
        string _fileName;
        string _viewPath;
        Model _model;
        ControllerContext _context;

        public ExcelResult(ControllerContext context, string viewPath, string fileName, Model model)
        {
            this._context = context;
            this._fileName = fileName;
            this._viewPath = viewPath;
            this._model = model;
        }
         protected string RenderViewToString()
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                var view = new WebFormView(_viewPath);
                var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<Model>(_model);
                var viewCxt = new ViewContext(_context, view, vdd, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
                viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
        void WriteFile(string content)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + _fileName);
            context.Response.Charset = "";
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            context.Response.Write(content);
            context.Response.End();
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            string content = this.RenderViewToString();
            this.WriteFile(content);
        }
    }
```

All of this works in Firefox but not in IE. Could it be something with the Response headers? That was my first guess but I wouldn't even know where to begin looking for something wrong.

The error that comes back from IE is this:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does your ExportToExcel code get hit in the debugger?

Comment: Yup and it gets all the way to the ExecuteResult method in the ExcelResult class, which is where it would then return the ActionResult in MVC, and that's where it pops up the error.

Comment: context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
can cause this problem over https. Do you have the site on https? Give it a try after commenting it.

Comment: Site is on http: not https: -- did you want me to comment that line of code in the WriteFile method and try it?

Comment: Hey bro you were right. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set

```
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

in IE.

Comment: why not - what difference does it make to IE?